# Is my website slow?

Tags: performance, apache, webserver, lan

First of all - please let me say thank you for taking the time to look at this post.

I have a problem - we host many websites on a server at our offices and from time-to-time receive complaints that the website is running slow (or worse still the pages do not load at all). The urls to some of our sites are:

```
www.jamaicatravelspecialist.co.uk
www.seychellessuperstar.co.uk
www.thebusinesstravelmag.com
www.sellingtravelmedia.com
```

to name but a few.....

Not all users experience these problems - the sites run fine from within the office and from a few home pc's I have managed to test them on - but we do get occasional calls saying they are slow to load from users based in other offices (generally on their own LAN) - or worse still do not load at all (mainly when using Chrome).  The few sites I have been able to visit this problem tends to be resolved (temporarily) by clearing the browsing history from any browsers.

I just want to gauge just HOW MANY people this is affecting and hopefully tell whether it is a problem with our webserver or a remote problem with customers LAN.

I have looked into this thoroughly and have failed to come up with a decent explanation or solution.

Wonder if any of you good folks can help!

Thanks

J

Comment: First site loaded fine for me sub 500ms latency. I think your going to get downvoted for this though. It is off-topic for this site. It has no real answer and is not for a specific problem to do with coding.

Comment: @DavidT - well thanks for checking anyway, much appreciated. Well I should perhaps try a different forum. But it had been suggested in the past that it MAY be down to coding.

Comment: Well thanks for checking anyway. I will perhaps try another forum - it has been previously suggested that it may be down to coding - but I am not convinced.

Comment: It could be due to coding, I have had similar problems in the past. However, without giving us code to debug or see whats wrong its impossible to help. Try and narrow it down. Use a debugger to look at things like database query times or something like [New Relic](http://newrelic.com/sp/brand?utm_source=GOOG&utm_medium=adwords&utm_content=rpm&utm_campaign=RPM&utm_term=NewRelicApi&mpc=PS-GOOG-RPM-EN-SIGNUP-Europe-Brand-NewRelic-LP3Api&gclid=CjwKEAjwkf-gBRCd-b2m2aOo0EQSJABMeQDkzd1ZAxlYW9TtPHolOYQi8QKBUL2kFXg0kuJu3r_RNRoC7JTw_wcB) to find out where the bottle neck is.

Answer (score 0):

Your question seems to boil down to

- how do you monitor performance *experienced* by your customers
- how do you identify the cause

That the issues appear to be intermittent implies that the content you are producing is probably OK - the issue is either with external services incorporated at the browser or with the infrastructure between you and your customers.

You need to monitor and capture performance data continuiuously to detect what's hapenning. How you go about this depends on how much money and time you have to spend. Google analytics provides very basic performance measurement, and for low volumes it's free.

If you've got time to spend on this, then Boomerang + Graphite captures a lot more useful information.

If you also track the response times for each request measured on your webserver (log '%D') then you'll see issues with your infrastructure such as slow database etc.

If you've got lots of money, have a look at the commercial offerings such as CA's Gomez. But do be aware that performance management is complex and despite what the salesman will tell you RUM (real user monitoring) is only part of the APM (application Performance Management) toolkit.

> the sites run fine from within the office and from a few home pc's

Web Performance is very sensitive to latency. Are you using a proxy which can simulate high latency and/or packet loss? This can be done with the QOS tools in Linux, or a proxy such as the Charles proxy.

> tends to be resolved (temporarily) by clearing the browsing history from any browsers

This suggests a problem with 304 responses: the content is marked as expired in the users cache but no new caching information is suplied when the client make a conditional request. Often simply touching the modification time on the cacheable content files wil give a temporary repreive. You should be able to see if this is happenning from the volume of 304 respopnses in your logs.